# ControllerContext and ViewData Outside Scope of Controller - MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am rendering PartialViews/Models with the method below in order to template emails that get sent out.

I am using the code below to convert the partial and model into an html string that I can pass to my email sending code.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            throw new ArgumentException("No View Path Provided.");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, this lives in the BaseController, I would like to move it out into a helper method so that I can move my email model building out/sending out of the controller too.

**The problem is I don't have access to ViewData/TempData/ControllerContext**

I can new up a ControllerContext but I don't know what to do about ViewData/TempData.

This is how I would use what I have in the Controller currently:

```
//Do Stuff in Controller

var html = RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/Mail/_ForgotPassword.cshtml", new MailModel { Username = "Skrillex", SomethingElse = "foo" });

//Send the Email
```

Comment: Are you using tempdata/viewdata in the rendering of the view? If not why not passing empty ones?

Comment: I am using the ViewData to set the Model.

Comment: So why is it not a strongly typed view? Did you have to use loose view?

Comment: "~/Views/Mail/_ForgotPassword.cshtml" is strongly typed. It appears that ViewData.Model = model; is setting the Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but the problem is your eagerness to complete separation, it is rather too eager.

You are using Razor view engine to render your rich text HTML email. A very noble approach. However, this means that you will be very close to your presentation layer and running this from outside a controller - in my view - does not make a lot of sense.

I believe you need to make (if not already made):

- Your email Razor view as strongly typed
- Let the rendering called in the controller as usual
- Rendering would be as simple as passing the model to the Render method
- Take out the building of your email model out to the helper you wish. This would not require any presentation layer logic and as such oblivious to it.

**So the point is, calling of the rendering does not need to go out of the controller, building of the email model should.**

Now if you are doing all of that it means I have not understood your question and requires more explanation.

Comment: So, for instance, I would make a MailController that returns strings?  And just leave the RenderToHTML method in BaseController or even move it up to MailController?  Then in the Account/Register action, for instance, when I need to send a success email: Do my register stuff, build mail model, call Mail/RenderRegisterEmail Action and pass the string it generates to the email sender?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance or static property of BaseController in the helper class as shown below,

```
public sealed class Helper {
///Gets or sets BaseController
public BaseController { get; set; }
#region "Constructors"
/// <summary>
/// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="Helper" /> class.
/// </summary>
public Helper() : base() {

}
/// <summary>
/// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="Helper" /> class.
/// </summary>
public Helper(BaseController baseController) : this() {
   this.BaseController = baseController;
}
#endregion
public void SendEmail(){
   // Here you can call your RenderPartialViewToString from the BaseController
 var m_RenderPartialViewToString = this.BaseController.RenderPartialViewToString( .......);
}}
```

Regards. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 methods for Razor rendering emails that need to be sent out side of a controller... first I passed the ControllerContext to my service layer which worked as expected, but not ideal....  Often my services are used by command line apps or compiled into a Windows Service where there is no ControllerContext available... On my second attempt I used this Razor render engine: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ or https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine